# Can't figure out how to fix "list index out of range"

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
keys = input('Enter sentence to repeat type')

try:
    keyslist = keys.split(' ')
    length = len(keys)
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('`'):
            quit()
        
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        keyboard.press(keyslist[i])
        i = i + 1
        time.sleep(0.01)
    time.sleep(0.08)
except Exception as exp:
    print(exp)
    selection()
```

I'm trying to get it to keep typing the same thing over and over. But when I run the code I get "`list index out of range`" How do I fix this?

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this:

```
keyslist = keys.split(' ')
length = len(keys)
```

Since `keyslist` is defined as being `keys` but without spaces, it will always be as short as, or shorter than, `keys`.

For example, if I input `'a s d f'`, then `keyslist = ['a', 's', 'd', 'f']` (four elements), but `len(keys) = 7`. Note that 7 > 4.

So, when you do this:

```
i = 0
while i < length:
    keyboard.press(keyslist[i])
```

eventually, `i` will reach some number that exceeds the length of `keyslist` while still not being the length of `keys`. In my example, that's `i = 4` (since lists are zero-indexed, the highest index in `keyslist` is 3).

---

Simplest solution is just to replace

```
length = len(keys)
```

with

```
length = len(keyslist)
```

or just remove that line entirely, and take the length of `keyslist` at the while loop:

```
while i < len(keyslist):
```